# Why would you use a class method constructor versus alloc/init?

Tags: objective-c, memory-management, constructor

There are two choices for constructors in Objective C/Cocoa:

**1. Class Constructor**

```
Product *product = [Product productWithIdentifier:@"Chocolate"];
// Use product
```

**2. Alloc/init Constructor**

```
Product *product = [[Product alloc] initWithIdentifier:@"Chocolate"];
// Use product
[product release];
```

**What I do**

- I tend to use the class method just because it looks cleaner and you don't need a release.
- I see a lot of alloc/init - what's the advantage to doing it this way?

**My Question**

- Which one is preferable? Or is it just a matter of taste?

**Code**

For context, the class Product would have the following:

```
+(Product *)productWithIdentifier:(NSString *)identifier_ {
   return [[[[self class] alloc] initWithIdentifier:identifier] autorelease];
}

-(Product *)initWithIndentifier:(NSString *)identifier_ {
   self = [super init]
   if (self) {
       identifier = identifier_;
   }
   return self;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you're using ARC, there's not that much of a difference between the two. If you're not using ARC, the difference is extremely important.

The `alloc/init` combination gives you an owning reference. That means you must `release` it later on. The `classnameWithFoo` variant returns a non-owning reference. You may not `release` it.

This follows the usual Cocoa naming conventions. All methods return non-owning (autoreleased) instances, except for the methods that start with `alloc`, `copy`, `mutableCopy` and `new`. These return owning references that you must `release`.

Which one to use is mostly a matter of taste. However, if you need temporary objects that you can dispose quickly the `alloc` variant results in slightly fewer method calls (the `autorelease`) and in a loop, it also reduces the maximum memory footprint. However, in most cases this reduced cost is neglectable.

Comment: So close between these two answers, but this is very slightly better because it mentions the memory footprint issue. But then again the other answer mentions "stringing" calls together. I wish I could choose both!

Answer (score 5):

IMO, the biggest difference between the two approaches comes from the fact that using a "class constructor" you get an autoreleased object; this is the most convenient option when you:

1. assign the allocated object to a `retain` properties;
2. when you create "temporary" objects (think of the various `NSString` methods that build a string from another string: in many case it happens you need to "chain" such calls; the constructor allows you to "forget" about memory management);
3. when you add the object to some object that retains it (think: `addSubview`)

In such cases the syntactical advantage of "class constructor" is foremost, but I think it also makes your code "safer" in terms of memory management.

On the other hand, when you create an object to assign it to an `assign` property (or directly to an ivar for which you have no property), then `alloc/init` will do perfectly and be preferable to the "constructor" (IMO).

So, in the end, it depends on the way you are going to use the objects you allocate. The class constructor is a convenience method.